# mysql query to select username that are equal the password

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query to select the rows that the username and password are the same.

example:

username: `math123`, password: `math123`

This is what i tried: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username == password;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the keyword binary in the WHERE clause to have an exact match.(Otherwise, MySQL would treat characters case-insensitively when comparing string values)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE binary username = password;
```

Note, passwords are usually stored after they are encrypted. For instance, you can only view the hash value of MySQL users' password in `mysql.users` table. There are functions to encrypt strings at your proposal. e.g `select password('your_password');`  and  more secure ones such as `sha2('password_string',512)`

Comment: the password function was never intended to be used except for setting passwords for mysql users. it was removed in mysql 8.  there are no functions in mysql really suited to password hashing, you should do it in the client.

Comment: @ysth Does this mean it's no longer safe to use more secure ones like `sha2('password_value',512)` ?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/how-secure-are-sha256-salt-hashes-for-password-storage

Comment: it has never been a good idea to use general purpose hashing functions for passwords, even if manually salting.